# WGET not working but CURL works on the same address/host?

Tags: linux, wget, curl

WGET give me this error:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden 2015-11-23 12:07:06 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

If I try the same URL (it’s an internal network Apache server, firewall isn’t blocking) with CURL the download works fine. I’m using the basic parameters, port 80… just WGET and the URL.

I have no log error in HTTPD at server which contains the file (.bin).

Hope someone could help because I use a lot of WGET commands in scripts there is already running in some machines.

Comment: What gives `curl -IL <URI>`?

Comment: [root@p57065 tmp]# curl -IL int.myhost.com/pacotes/linuxupdate.bin
HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Server: squid/2.7.STABLE7
Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2015 16:39:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 4519
X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
X-Cache: MISS from ajax.caxias.rs.gov.br
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from int.myhost.com:3128
Via: 1.0 ajax.caxias.rs.gov.br:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE7)
Connection: close

Comment: That's weird. You are getting a 403 with curl too. Is the output really the linuxupdate.bin? (md5sum)

Comment: yes if i try curl -O "URL" it downloads 100% and the file is at folder...

Comment: Try it with an additional header: `wget --header="Host: int.myhost.com" <URI>`

Comment: Maybe the server is checking `User-Agent`, and allows curl, but not wget.